# IE9 and Tracking Blocker

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html-email

I have a template used by our Email marketing, it was developed more than a year and has worked fine up to the release of IE9. The page is table based, and uses graphics embedded as cell background

```
<TD height="83" background="http://www.myDomain.com/Content/images/email/spacer.gif" width="1" border="0">
```

because, at the time of development that's the consensus 'best way' to accomodate the various user agents. IE9 includes new 'Tracker Blocking' methods and it's decided that my banner graphics don't cut the mustard.

It's not a matter of syntax - IE's F12 dev tools is explicitly reporting 2 graphics as blocked.

I'm not tracking - i'm not spamming. I'm looking for info on how IE goes about deciding what to show and what to block.

thx

ADDENDUM: The error message reads: SEC 7114: A download in this page was blocked by Tracking Protection.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain images can be blocked by Tracking Protection, either explicitly (they're in a TPL) or heuristically (if they are used across many top-level-domains).  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/12/07/ie9-and-privacy-introducing-tracking-protection-v8.aspx for more information.

What is the exact text of the message in the Developer Tools console?

Comment: Initially the page had cross-domain references. Initially i though i'd cracked the nut by aligning the domains but turned out otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

IE9's Tracking Protection Lists (TPL) just block all requests from certain domains. The domains can be explicitly defined by the user, and they can subscribe to lists which block many of the most common tracking domains.

I suspect you are suffering from the latter. The only way around it is to point to a different domain which IE9 is not blocking.

Comment: I'd have to be a little surprised to be listed - i'm really small-low bandwidth, not to mention  (or re-mention) the fact the my usage profile isn't going to raise red flags - at least not without lots of other folks whining about it.  I'm more included to suspect a cache needs to be cleared.

Comment: Ah OK - I thought you were sending from an ESP like MailChimp. In the case that it's just your domain, yes that would be strange.